# Unable to connect web server VM from my netscaler VM

Tags: vmware-workstation, netscaler

I have created a lab to learn VPX ADC and my lab environment as per below. All the below 3 machines are connected via VMWare Workstation Bridged Network.

- Host - Windows 10, IP Address is 192.168.2.123, Firewall & Antivirus.
- VM 1 - Windows 2016, IP Address is 192.168.2.125, Firewall & Antivirus.
- VM 2 - Citrix ADC Release NS13.1 27.59.nc, NSIP is 192.168.2.221, SNIP, 192.168.2.222

I am trying to configure a load balancer in ADC. I added the *load balancing > Server* as 192.168.2.105 which shows the *STATE* as *ENABLED*. Then I went and added a *Service Group* and selected the server as 192.168.2.125 and port 80. What is happening now is that the Service Group shows that the *STATE* is *ENABLED* but the *EFFECTIVE STATE* is *DOWN*.

I investigated and found that I am unable to ping or telnet on port 80 from ADC (VM 2) to VM 1 and error shown in DOWN state of Service Group is "failure - timeout during tcp connection establishment stage". I am not able to understand why so since the web page hosted on VM 1 (192.168.2.125) is accessible just fine from the Host (192.168.2.123) on port 80. Also, the load balancing feature has been enabled in the ADC.

Could you please help me understand what is going wrong in this config?

Answer (score 0):

That pretty much sounds like a VMware Workstation issue rather than a NetScaler/ADC issue.

Can you check whether or not host isolation is active on the Bridged network? First, make sure they can see each other before trying anything else; a ping should work given they are next to each other network-wise.

Comment: That’s the pretty part. I am even dumber in vmware than I am in Netscaler. Can you guide me please?